# Can assigning to a Cursor.Position throw an exception?

Tags: .net, winapi

Presumably the .NET's code

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

internally uses `SetCursorPos()` WINAPI function, which (according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in some cases may return `false`.

So how would I handle the case when `Cursor.Position` hasn't been changed successfully? Does .NET provide some guarantee to always move cursor to a specified position?

**UPD**: the thing is I do have already a tiny C++ program that moves cursor to a left bottom corner using `SetCursorPos`. And the thing is it doesn't move a cursor every time. I'm not proficient enough in C++ to debug the case so I decided to rewrite it in .NET to see a difference.

What I need it for: to run some tests (selenium webdriver) I need a mouse cursor to be not over the browser window, because I'm sending the mouse events in test cases manually and a real cursor interferes with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how would I handle the case when Cursor.Position hasn't been changed successfully?

The only way to even test for this is to try to get the Position immediately after setting it.

> Does .NET provide some guarantee to always move cursor to a specified position?

The `Cursor.Position` setter should succeed any time the cursor's position can be moved.  There is no way to guarantee this, as it's possible (though highly unlikely) that the Windows API can fail.  Any failure would likely be due to a non-standard environment (sometimes VM's can cause this, a fullscreen Direct3D app is active, or a screensaver is running).

The other alternative, of course, would be to PInvoke `SetCursorPos` yourself, and call `GetLastError` if the method returns `false`.

Comment: "though highly unlikely" --- I will add some explanation I should have added initially

Comment: @zerkms I listed the main reasons this tends to happen - what do you need this for, and what's causing the failure?

Comment: added an UPDate. I cannot say what causes that, the fails are sporadic :-(

Comment: @zerkms I would suggest using PInvoke (or your original C++ project) and checking GetLastError - it should tell you why it's failing, which might help diagnose and determine the best approach to solve (ie: just call again, etc)

Comment: yep, it's actually a good idea. If it will continue failing with .net implementation I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it out, and it appears that .NET safely handles issues if you try to set the position to a location that is not on screen (i.e. `new Point(-1, -1)`).

If you want to check if the position has indeed changed you could do this:

```
Point oldPos = Cursor.Position;
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
if (oldPos == Cursor.Position)
{
    // cursor position not set
}
```

Although that may not be an error in most cases. I'm not sure what other issues can occur, but if you're really worried about it, you can always use a `try-catch` block:

```
try {
    Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    // Unable to set cursor position.
}
```

Although I doubt that would be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN documentation [Cursor.Position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is identical to [Cursor.MousePosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) does not throw any exceptions.

The framework wrappers the WinApi call and catches the exception without rethrowing.